# Did Mormons protest social issues with the American flag in 1885?

Tags: united-states, lds

Recently several articles from various sources have been claiming that Mormons lowered the flag to half mast on July 4, 1885 to protest persecution from the US government concerning their "Civil disobedience."

> The Deseret News kept its flag at half-staff until dark and defended the action as an exhibition of sorrow by Utah's people "over the decadence of their liberties." When rumors claimed the Mormons planned a similar protest on Pioneer Day, President Cleveland ordered Army units in the West to prepare to put down a rebellion in Utah.

[Source](https://heritage.utah.gov/history/uhg-slt-early-mormons-civil-disobedience)

Are these stories accurate?

Comment: Doesn't really seem remarkable if they did. Why are you skeptical?

Comment: @fredsbend I think it is probably true, but seeing that the current climate of conservatives angering at protests against the flag/anthem, bringing up this topic to largely conservative Mormons has a certain "gotcha" feel to it. I've only seen it from people who stand to gain by putting Mormons down, so I'm curious to see if it is true.